# Swift - Remove an array from dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, dictionary

I am trying to remove an element from an array inside of a dictionary but the value aren't removed from the dictionary when I remove it from the tableview. Is the way I try to remove the array wrong?

```
marker.buttonAction["button actions array"]?.remove(at: indexPath.row)

//Function to remove array from dictionary and tableview.
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {

        if let marker = markUpPlist.arrayObjects.filter({$0.tagClip == currentSelectedMarker}).first {

            print(marker.buttonAction["button actions array"]?[indexPath.row].action)

                marker.buttonAction["button actions array"]?.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
}

//Variable which stores the dictionary
var buttonAction : [String: [ButtonAction]] = [:]

//ButtonAction array
class ButtonAction: Codable {
var action: String
var array_linked_of_buttons: [[String:String]]

init(action: String, array_linked_of_buttons: [[String:String]]) {
 self.action = action
 self.array_linked_of_buttons = array_linked_of_buttons
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that I forgot to re-save the data after deleting it.. the code works fine and I am leaving the question if that helps others.

Comment: arrayObjects is of classes or structs ?

Comment: arrayObjects is a class

Comment: if your dataSource is `markUpPlist.arrayObjects` then it's strange a copy with a class